# Form only checking first value on submit function?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

The form first check all the values in Hour are either a whole number or .5
The problem is that is only checking the first value.

My guess would be that the problem is that there can only be one ID for each
form submitted.

How can I make it that it will check all the values before i insert the values
in the table.

Right now its checking the first record, if the first record pass the function 
then no matter what the other numbers in will still insert into the table.

```
<table >      
     <cfoutput query="GetEmployees" group="dept">   

     <tr><th >#dept_name#</th></tr> 
      <tr><th >Hour</th><th>Name</th><th>Expiration Date (mm/dd/ccyy)</th></tr> 
<cfoutput>   
     <cfset cnt= cnt+1>                                
     <tr>                                     
     <td><input type="text"  size="2"  name="time#cnt#" id="add_time" value="" ></td>        
     <td> #emp_namefirst#                                        
     <input type="hidden"  name="emp_id#cnt#" value="#emp_id#"></td>           
     <td><input type="text"  name="expiration_time#cnt#" id="experition_date" value="#dateformat(nextdate, "mm/dd/yyyy")#"></td>     
     </tr>                                                                               

     </cfoutput>                
 </cfoutput> 

</table>

    <p><input type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" value=""></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    var value = document.getElementById("add_time").value;
    console.log(value);
    if (!isNumber(value) || (value % 0.5) !== 0) {

        alert("Please make sure all time is either a whole number or .5");
        return false;
    }   
}

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ID` attribute should be unique per document object (the input in this case). You've only made a reference to ONE ID with the value of "add_time". With the code as it is, I think it's referencing the last instance of `ID="add_time"`. You should add the `#cnt#` variable to the ID to make them all unique.

In order to validate them all, you could use CF to create all of the JS code to check each input field by wrapping the relevant JS code with a `CFOUTPUT` using the same `#cnt#` variable to make a check per field. Or you can learn jQuery and figure out how to add a `class` attribute to each input and run the validation for all objects of that class.

Finally, your alert message should contain some kind of indicator as to the field that's causing the error. Otherwise, the user will have to pick and choose until they get the fields correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is a formatted comment.  I have some observations.

First, parseFloat() and parseInt() won't necessarily return NaN for non-numeric strings.  Be careful with that.  For example, try parseFloat with "1.y7" and see what you get.

Second, rather than displaying a message when the form is submitted, you can simply empty the field in the onBlur event if the value is not what you want.

Finally, rather than this:

```
<input type="text"  size="2"  name="time#cnt#" id="add_time" value="" >      
emp_namefirst#                                        
<input type="hidden"  name="emp_id#cnt#" value="#emp_id#">
<input type="text"  
name="expiration_time#cnt#" 
id="experition_date" 
value="#dateformat(nextdate, "mm/dd/yyyy")#">
```

You might find this to be simpler:

```
<input type="text"  size="2"  name="time#emp_id#" id="add_time#emp_id#" value="" >      

<input type="text"  
name="expiration_time#emp_id#" 
id="experition_date#emp_id#" 
value="#dateformat(nextdate, "mm/dd/yyyy")#">
```

When you process the form after submission, you do something like this:

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="formfield">
<cfif left(formfield, 4) is "time">
<cfset thisEmpId = right(formfield, len(formfield) - 4)>
```

Then you use arrayNotation to reference the values of the form fields.  For example:

```
 insert into sometable
 (emp_id, time)
 values
 (<cfqueryparam value = "#thisEmpId#">
 , <cfqueryparam value = "#form['time' & thisEmpId]#">
 )
```

or whatever it is you need to do with those values.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is not necessary here. (Alright, it's never necessary but it's very easy to iterate over classnames in plain javascript.)

[Demonstration fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ryjatxbq/1/) - Note that the javascript in the demo fiddle has an extra `return false;` that always happens. This is only because the fiddle demonstration did not like a form that actually submits. Just remove it.

Javascript:

```
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    var ftimes = document.getElementsByClassName("add_timebox");
    var fflag = 0;
    for(i=0;i<ftimes.length;i++) {
        var value = ftimes[i].value;
        console.log(i + ': ' + value);
        if (!isNumber(value) || (value % 0.5) !== 0) {
            fflag = 1;
        }
    }
    if(fflag==1) {
        alert("Please make sure all time is either a whole number or .5");
        return false;
    }
    // Remove this return false.
    return false;
}

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Sample HTML. Notice how I gave the timebox a class value.

```
<form method="post" id="form"><table >      

     <tr><th >#dept_name#</th></tr> 
      <tr><th >Hour</th><th>Name</th><th>Expiration Date (mm/dd/ccyy)</th></tr> 
     <tr>                                     
     <td><input type="text"  size="2"  name="time1" id="add_time" value="" class="add_timebox"></td>        
     <td> #emp_namefirst#                                        
     <input type="hidden"  name="emp_id#cnt#" value="#emp_id#"></td>           
     <td><input type="text"  name="expiration_time#cnt#" id="experition_date" value="#dateformat(nextdate, "mm/dd/yyyy")#"></td>     
     </tr>                                                                               
     <tr>                                     
     <td><input type="text"  size="2"  name="time2" id="add_time" value="" class="add_timebox"></td>        
     <td> #emp_namefirst#                                        
     <input type="hidden"  name="emp_id#cnt#" value="#emp_id#"></td>           
     <td><input type="text"  name="expiration_time#cnt#" id="experition_date" value="#dateformat(nextdate, "mm/dd/yyyy")#"></td>     
     </tr>                                                                               
     <tr>                                     
     <td><input type="text"  size="2"  name="time3" id="add_time" value="" class="add_timebox"></td>        
     <td> #emp_namefirst#                                        
     <input type="hidden"  name="emp_id#cnt#" value="#emp_id#"></td>           
     <td><input type="text"  name="expiration_time#cnt#" id="experition_date" value="#dateformat(nextdate, "mm/dd/yyyy")#"></td>     
     </tr>                                                                               
</table>

    <p><input type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" value="Click Me!"></p>
</form>
```